# Flask Model Group-By DateTime Field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a flask application with a Model class `Journey`:

```
class Journey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    origin_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    destination_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    departure_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    travel_duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    origin = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[origin_id])
    destination = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[destination_id])
```

I would like to group all journeys that occurred within the same quarter of an hour and get the average of their travel duration. I basically need to group by the hour and the quarter. 
The groups could look like this:

Group 1 (hour 10 quarter 1)

- 15.01.2018 10:00
- 16.01.2018 10:07
- 20.01.2018 10:14

Group 2 (hour 10 quarter 2)

- 17.01.2018 10:15
- 16.01.2018 10:23
- 20.01.2018 10:29

Group 3 (hour 10 quarter 3)

- 15.01.2018 10:30
- 16.01.2018 10:37
- 20.01.2018 10:44

Group 4 (hour 10 quarter 4)

- 15.01.2018 10:45
- 16.01.2018 10:52
- 20.01.2018 10:59

Is there a way to create the fields `departure_hour` and `departure_quarter` based off of the field `departure_time`? This way I could get the averages with the following query:

```
db.session.query(Journey.departure_hour, Journey.departure_quarter,
         func.avg(Journey.travel_duration)).group_by(Journey.departure_hour,
Journey.departure_quarter).all()
```

Or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXTRACT expressions to extract relevant fields, if supported by your database or SQLAlchemy dialect. A [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) is a good way to hide all that:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Journey(db.Model):                                           
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                               
    origin_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    destination_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False)
    departure_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    travel_duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    origin = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[origin_id])
    destination = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[destination_id])

    @hybrid_property                  
    def departure_hour(self):
        return self.departure_time.hour

    @departure_hour.expression
    def departure_hour(cls):
        return db.func.extract('hour', cls.departure_time).cast(db.Integer)

    @staticmethod
    def _extract_quarter_hour(minute):
        # Rounds down to nearest quarter, alternatively
        # floor(minute / 15) * 15
        return minute - minute % 15

    @hybrid_property
    def departure_quarter(self):
        return self._extract_quarter_hour(self.departure_time.minute)

    @departure_quarter.expression
    def departure_quarter(cls):
        minute = db.func.extract('minute', cls.departure_time).cast(db.Integer)
        return cls._extract_quarter_hour(minute)
```

With those in place your query should work pretty much as is.